# python selenium chromedriver xpath "no such element"

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running Python 3.6 on an iMac (OS: Sierra). I use ChromeDriver 2.33 and the latest version of the Selenium package (from PIPY). I'm trying to access (using `find_element_by_xpath`) the column elements of a table row as shown below:

[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxxiM.jpg)

I can access the first three cells (TH tags) embedded inside the row (TR tag). When I get to the 4th cell (TH tag) the chrome driver reports (via python) 'No such element'.

I'm waiting 10s of seconds after loading the page before trying to access the element (also, I can excess cell 1-3 for this row) so this is obviously not a timing issue.

The web element (cell #4) is visible in the web browser. Also, I used the web element search function in chrome developer to check the xpath (and it checks out just fine). Obviously, the issue is not that the element isn't visible.

I wonder what the issue is? Or at least I'd like some recommendation on how to debug this?

---

In response to comments: I use the following python call

> CHROMEDRIVER.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="mainContent_ugReservationGrid_tableGridParent"]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxxiM.jpg)/table/thead/tr[3]/th[INDEX]")'
>   where 'INDEX' is my loop-variable.. 1-3 works fine but when the loop
>   variable gets to 4 I get the exception '`No Such Element`'.

---

Replaced Chrome with Firefox & geckodriver: It seems to be an issue with the Chrome interface. Firefox works as expected w/o any other changes.

Comment: What is the call you use to you get the first three cells? To debug, I would start by checking if you are able to get all of the TR elements by using find_elements_by_tag_name (or whatever python uses for that call, I use C#). Create a function to get all elements on the page with the TR tag and print them to your console to make sure all are returned and then go from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not experiencing timing issues while referencing the other table cells, it would be worthwhile to further validate the xpath you're using for the element which you can never seem to reach.

Even though I tend to run all of my automation primarily through Chrome, I will still occasionally use Firefox with the FirePath plugin for picking/validating locators on a page. This plugin is particularly useful in that it will yield all matches for a given locator. One reason why automation might fail (or at least behave unpredictably) is that a locator might have more than one match.